# Why I use params in getInitialProps they are undefined when build in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this problem in Next.js. I call the API in `getInitialProps` and pass the `params` to my components then it works when I use it in mu project. But when I want to build it gives me error that the `params` are `undefined`.

This is how I call my API and pass it to component:

```
import BlogItem from './blogItem'
import axios from 'axios'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import { APIURL, replaceAll } from '../../../components/config'
const Post = (props) => {
  return (

    <BlogItem
      services ={props.services }

    />

  )
}

Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const id = query.id
  const urlTitle = encodeURI(query.title)
  const services  = null;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${APIURL}getservice`);
    services = response.data.response.posts;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  return {
services 
  }
}

export default withRouter(Post)
```

Comment: error coming here on this line ==> Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {????

Comment: no ever thing ok in npm run dev but when i use npm run build i have error like this :
Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/[title]/blogItem": TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Ok, i am guessing that `services` is not being returned correctly through the getinitialprops. Did you print services and ensure that it has correct values?

Comment: yes i print it i have values and i use it in my projet but i dont know why hen build it give undefined error :((

Comment: I got the same issue, not on the build process but leads to an internal server error. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you defined services as a `const` that contain `null`! the whole code seems fine. Try changing const to let:

```
Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const id = query.id
  const urlTitle = encodeURI(query.title)
  let services  = null; //this line

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${APIURL}getservice`);
    services = response.data.response.posts;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  console.log(services) //you should have the data right here

  return {services}
}
```

**Example :** 
Look at this example. Run it and navigate to `/about` page :

[image: Edit falling-wind-d9ych]

Comment: i get changed i get services in console log but and i get it in run dev but in build i dont get i have to use componentDidmount to set state but i dont want to use it

Comment: Although you have async-await, Maybe you should return the services in the try scope.
try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${APIURL}getservice`);
    services = response.data.response.posts;
    if(services) {return {services}}

  }

Comment: @ElyasPourmotazedy I uploaded an example for you with your own code. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your url params are passed into the querystring on the server,  In your case, something like this:

```
server.get('/page/:uid/:id', (req, res) => {
  const mergedQuery = Object.assign({}, req.query, req.params)
  return app.render(req, res, '/page', mergedQuery);
})
```

Then your getInitialProps can get them straight from the query, regardless of where it loads.